# Is Autism associated with an increased drowning risk for adults?

Tags: developmental-psychology, decision-making, behavior, autism

I have found several popular articles (e.g. [ScienceDaily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2014/07/140708121527.htm), [The Globe and Mail](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/kids-with-autism-have-a-higher-risk-of-drowning-its-time-we-do-something-about-it/article35188828/), and [WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/brain/autism/news/20170321/autism-greatly-boosts-kids-injury-risk-especially-for-drowning)) indicating that *children* with Autism have a significantly elevated risk of drowning. The general theory seems to be that the calming affect of water combines with a lack of situational awareness common in people with Autism to create a "perfect storm" situation in which the child is presented with highly appealing decision opportunities that they are not fully able to assess. A simple online search for "autism and drowning" turns up tons of articles and discussions about the risk of drowning in *children* with Autism.

Has a substantially elevated risk of drowning been shown to exist or not exist for *adults* with Autism? That is, is the risk of drowning for children simply more socially relevant today (e.g. drowning out any studies and warnings of potential linkages for adults), or is there substantial reason to believe that the maturity that comes with age does or does not reduce the risk of drowning to control group levels?

Comment: Epilepsy is associated with an increased risk of drowning in adults. Autism and epilepsy often occur together.

Comment: @angela however, the etiology would seem to be completely different. Drownings from Autism seem to be based on judgment factors, rather than the sudden loss of brain function common in Epilepsy. That is, children with Autism drown because they have difficulty in the cognitive process of making "good" decisions, not because their brain suddenly seizes. Perhaps it's like the difference between software that produces unexpected results and software that locks up the computer.

Comment: I dont know the stats of it but i think its yes due to some reasons. 1. Less or no recognition of danger, 2. Can be easily influenced by peers or can be impulsively engage in risky act, 3. Problems with decision making and judgement. 4. Poor fine motor skills, may have inherent difficulties in tasks like riding bicycle or swimming.